# Different Grid structure for devices using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

, We have a requirement wherein we need the 12 Column Grid on Desktop as it is but on Tablet it should follow an 8 column grid. We wanted to know if this is possible in Bootstrap. If Yes, how do we do it?

Comment: you may override the bootstrap CSS with your own CSS for table to obtain 8 column

Comment: But the question is, how your elements will transform from 12 to 8 ?

Comment: Please describe the exact layout. How many actual columns units (instead of grid units) will be used for each device?

Comment: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#responsive-classes Have you tried anithing from there ?

Answer (score 0):

It will depends on your design as you know 12 columns cover full width now you need 8 columns of full width. So in this case you can use 'offset' properties to give column based space and implement your design. Another method is you can directly use source code of bootstrap in sass or less and call mixin directly as per your requirements.